# how do I return a pointer to an array from a function using a struct as the interface

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, interface

I am trying to create an interface to an array in C++.

In the code below 
`tmpClass[1].GetA()` returns 'w'
`tmpInterface[1]` causes an error.

Is there any way to define an interface so it can access the elements of the array?
How to I get `tmpInterface` to behave like `tmpClass`?

```
struct IA
{
    virtual char GetA() = 0;
    virtual void SetA(char pA) = 0;
};

class A:public IA
{
    public:
        A(){ var = 0; }
        A(char pVar){ var = pVar; }
        char GetA(){ return var; }
        void SetA(char pA){ var = pA; }
    private:
    int var;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B(){ 
            mA[0].SetA('c');
            mA[1].SetA('w');
            mA[2].SetA('6');
            mA[3].SetA('$');
        }

        int GetCount(){}
        IA* Get1(){ return mA; }
        A* Get2(){ return mA; }
    protected:
        A mA[4];
};


int main()
{
    B mainClass;
    IA *tmpInterface = mainClass.Get1();
    A *tmpClass = mainClass.Get2();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        //once i>0 then tmpInterface no longer points to a valid character
        //and program crashes
        System::Console::Write(
            "A = "+tmpClass[i].GetA()+
            " IA = "+tmpInterface[i].GetA()); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscript operator uses pointer arithmetic, and performing pointer arithmetic on a pointer whose type is different from the actual type of the object it points to is undefined behavior. §5.7 [expr.add]/p7:

> For addition or subtraction, if the expressions `P` or `Q` have type
>   “pointer to cv `T`”, where `T` is different from the cv-unqualified
>   array element type, the behavior is undefined. [ *Note*: In
>   particular, a pointer to a base class cannot be used for pointer
>   arithmetic when the array contains objects of a derived class type.
>   —*end note* ]

So, to index into an array of `A`s, you need an `A*`. If you want to use `IA` only, then you'd need to apply some programmer's panacea - indirection. Return an `IA **` pointing to the first element of an array of `IA *`, whose members each point to an `A`.

Comment: There is no way to create an interface to an array in c++ that will allow me to access its elements; unless I do the pointer math myself?

Answer (score 0):

Note that polymorphism only works with pointers or references to instances of a class, not with the instances directly. This is at the root of your problem.

You might consider using `std::vector<A*>` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

In effective C++,it says don't use polymorphism on array;
You can add a virtual function behave like operator [],eg:

```
struct IA
{
    //...
    virtual IA* Offset(int index)
    {
        return this + index;
    }
};

class A:public IA
{
public:
    //...
    virtual A* Offset(int index)
    {
        return this + index;
    }
};
```

then it works fine.

```
cout << "A = " << tmpClass->Offset(i)->GetA();
cout << " IA = " << tmpInterface->Offset(i)->GetA() << endl;
```

Besides,what is System::Console::Write in C++?

Comment: System::Console::Write   The visual studio wizard dropped that in when I created the C++ Console project.

Answer (score 0):

In an object of type `B`, you have an array of `A` objects. You return a pointer to the first element of the array in both the member functions `B::Get1()` and `B::Get2()`.

Let's say the lay out the array is:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    mA[0]     |    mA[1]     |    mA[2]     |    mA[3]     |         
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

When you execute

```
IA *tmpInterface = mainClass.Get1();
A *tmpClass = mainClass.Get2();
```

You have `tempInterface` and `tmpClass` pointing to the first element of `mA`.

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    mA[0]     |    mA[1]     |    mA[2]     |    mA[3]     |         
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
^
| 
tmpInterface as well as tmpClass
```

When you do arithmetic operations on `tmpInterface` and `tmpClass`, you will see very different results.

Where do `tmpInterface+1` and `tmpClass+1` point?

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    mA[0]     |    mA[1]     |    mA[2]     |    mA[3]     |         
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
      ^        ^
      |        | 
      |        tmpClass+1
      tmpInterface+1
```

Since `tmpClass` is of type `A*`,  `tmpClass+1` points to the next object in the array. However, since the type of `tmpInterface` is `IA*`, and `sizeof(IA)` is not the same as `sizeof(A)`, `tmpInterface+1` points to something in the middle. It does not point to an object of type `IA`. If you try to access `tmpInterface+1` as a `IA*`, you are going to get undefined behavior.